# Разбить строку на массив

Tags: php

Добрый вечер. Есть текст вида:

> Слово {слово1|слово2|слово3} другое
> слово {слово3|слово4|слово5} и т.д.

Блоков с вариантами слов может быть до бесконечности много, как и слов между ними.
Таких строк несколько тысяч, как в блоках, так и вне их присутствуют пробелы и знаки препинания.

Нужно, чтобы на выходе получился массив вида:

```
Array(
[0] => Слово
[1] => {слово1|слово2|слово3}
[2] => другое слово
[3] => {слово3|слово4|слово5}
[4] => и т.д.
)
```

Помогите реализовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если каждое слово - это действительно слово (то есть в нём нет пробелов), то это делается функцией [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

```
$s = "Слово {слово1|слово2|слово3} другое_слово {слово3|слово4|слово5}";
$a = explode(" ", $s);
print_r($a);
```

**UPD**

В таком случае используем регулярные выражения: http://www.debuggex.com/r/Z8IT9OjzwrHYDwfW

```
$s = "Несколько видов {больших массивов|строк|классов|различных функций} могут быть совершенно {разными|непохожими} по свойствам и качествам{.|!|?}";
$pattern = "/((\\w|\\s)+)|(\\{(((\\w|\\s|[.!?])|\\|)+)\\})/u";
preg_match_all($pattern, $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

http://ideone.com/uE78qz

Comment: Это было бы слишком просто, между словами, как в блоках, так и вне их присутствуют пробелы.   
И таких строк много, так что замена пробелов вручную не вариант.

Comment: Чтобы легче было понять, еще один пример:
> Несколько видов {больших массивов|строк|классов|различных функций} могут быть совершенно {разными|непохожими} по свойствам и качествам{.|!|?}

Comment: Подправил регулярку, теперь она понимает и русский алфавит.

Comment: Работает, благодарю :)

Answer (score 1):

[На javascript'е](http://jsfiddle.net/ivanovsuper/REeU2/) бонусом генератор предложений ))

Comment: Спасибо, пригодилось)